# Auto-detect video card driver

Tags: xorg, drivers, lfs, graphic-card

I've recently made a Linux From Scratch with Kernel 4.5.0 on virtualbox.
In the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` I have listed my video driver as `vesa`

However when I boot into the live session in my laptop, the GUI doesn't start with fatal error **"No screens found"**. If I change the "vesa" to "intel" it boots fine but then it stops working in virtualbox

Is there any way I can detect the driver automatically during boot on target computer and make necessary change before starting X